# How to delete a elasticache subnet group with cloud custodian?

Tags: cloudcustodian, amazon-elasticache

I want to use cloud custodian to cleanup some aws resources.( elasticache in this case) .
However ; I got error when trying to delete `elasticache subnet groups`.  According to [custodian cache.subnet-group documentation](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/aws/resources/cache-subnet-group.html), `delete` is not a valid action for cache.subnet-group.
How do I perform delete in this case?

my policy file.

```
policies:
  - name: cleanup-elasticache-subnet-group
    resource: aws.cache-subnet-group
    filters:
        - type: value
          key: "CacheSubnetGroupName"
          op: contains
          value: foo
    actions:
        - type: delele  >>> !!! delete is not a valaid action type !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Cloud Custodian doesn't natively provide the delete action today, your main options are:

- [Open a feature request](https://github.com/cloud-custodian/cloud-custodian/issues/new/choose) for an `aws.cache-subnet-group.delete` action.
- Use Cloud Custodian to report/notify on subnet groups you need to delete, but handle the actual deletion with external tools.

For what it's worth, you can review open feature requests [here](https://github.com/cloud-custodian/cloud-custodian/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Akind%2Fenhancement). I didn't see any for this action, but it's always good to check!